# Referring to web resources from web resources

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have uploaded two Resources - *a.HTML* and *b.PNG*. In *a* I'd like to display *b* and according to [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/darrenliu/archive/2011/02/07/reference-an-image-in-web-resource-from-site-map-or-ribbon.aspx) I should go like this.

```
<img src="$webresource:b.png">
```

However, I'd like to know if there's an other syntax (preferably one that doesn't includes the *$webresource:* part). I've tried with some different combinations but didn't really succeeded.

Comment: If this answered your issue, please mark it as answered. Doing so will help encourage others to assist in any future questions you may have.

Comment: @GregOwens What do you mean by "this answer"? This is my question, not an answer... I'm not sure what you'd like me to mark as answered.

Comment: Bad choice of words. If your question has been answered, which I believe it is by my response below, then mark _that_ as answered ;)

Comment: @GregOwens It sure was. Sorry for being slow. And the choice of Words wasn't bad. I was just very tired and didn't connect the dots properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article you link to explains how to reference a web resource from within the Ribbon or Site Map. This is different to your goal which is to reference one web resource from another.

The [CRM SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309473.aspx#BKMK_ReferencingWebResources) states:

> When referencing a web resource from areas that do not support using
>   the $webresource: directive,...

(Note that Web Resources themselves do not support the `$webresource:` directive)

> ...a relative URL can be used. To enable
>   this, we recommend that you use a consistent naming convention for the
>   web resources that reflect a virtual file structure. The solution
>   publisher’s customization prefix will always be included as a prefix
>   to the name of the web resource. This can represent a virtual ”root”
>   folder for all web resources added by that publisher. You can then use
>   the forward slash character (/) to simulate a folder structure that
>   will be honored by the web server.

So if you have two web resources called:

1. new_/html/mypage.html
2. new_/img/myimage.png

In `mypage.html` you can refer to the image thusly:

```
<img src="../img/myimage.png"/>
```

By implication, if your resources (`a.HTML` and `b.PNG`) do not have virtual paths, it should be sufficient to reference the image like this (though I strongly recommend using the aforementioned Virtual Path convention):

```
<img src="b.PNG"/>
```

Comment: Just a quick note - your <img> tags should use forward slashes, and in the final example the initial "./" is implied. So <img src="b.PNG"> is sufficient.